# OpenCV and python - crop webcam stream and save it to file

Tags: python, opencv, crop

I want to save to file a specific area of the video recorded by my webcam.
I'm defining the limits of the area I want to record by using the variables x_0, x_1 (width) and y_0, y_1 (height), cropping the recorded frame and saving it to file. I'm also giving those dimensions to cv2.VideoWriter.
Here's my code:

```py
import cv2


def main():
    # these are the limits of the cropped area
    x_0 = 100
    x_1 = 440
    y_0 = 0
    y_1 = 450

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    # passing the dimensions of cropped area to VideoWriter
    out_video = cv2.VideoWriter('recording.avi', fourcc, 15.0, (y_1-y_0, x_1-x_0))

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret == True:
            frame_crop = frame[y_0:y_1, x_0:x_1]
            out_video.write(frame_crop)
            cv2.imshow("crop", frame_crop)
            key = cv2.waitKey(25)
            if key == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when I stop the recording, the file is generated, but it's empty.
The problem is with how I'm managing the cropping, because if I just use, say:

```
out_video = cv2.VideoWriter('recording.avi', fourcc, 15.0, (640, 480))
```

and save the whole frame (by using 'out_video.write(frame_crop)') instead of the cropped one, it works.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(y_1-y_0, x_1-x_0)` -- width and height are in wrong order.

Comment: Feeling kinda stupid, I noticed after posting the question. Got confused because for the array slicing you go the opposite way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video size param in `VideoWriter` should be of the shape `(width, height)`

You need to change your call to it to be like this:

```
out_video = cv2.VideoWriter('recording.avi', fourcc, 15.0, (x_1-x_0, y_1-y_0))
```